# Access class object builtin values from class (not class member) scope

Tags: python, class

How can you access class values from within the top level class scope?  What I mean by that is, how do you do something like:

```
class FooClass(object):
    zeroith_base = __bases__[0]
    .
    .
    .
```

What I'm specifically trying to do in this case is derive the metaclasses of all base classes to dynamically generate a metaclass that subclasses all the base classes' metaclasses to get past metclass conflict problems.  I found http://code.activestate.com/recipes/204197-solving-the-metaclass-conflict/, and while all the concepts make sense to me, the actual code of the recipe is just beyond my ability to follow it.  I don't want to use code I can't understand though, so instead, I tried to implement my own, more rudimentary system, but I'm stuck at square one trying to inspect the class object during creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot inspect a class prior to its creation, and it has not yet been created yet until the suite of statements, or class body, have finished executing. The first time you have access to this information would be in the `MetaClass.__new__` method of the class creating the class in question, or the execution of the thing creating the class in question, which technically need not be a meta-class or a class at all (as in the example below).

Here is a very rough prototype that probably does not work in all cases, but works in the simple case, and is probably easier to follow than the recipe.

```
def meta_class_synthesize(name, bases, attrmap):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    metas = [type(base) for base in bases]
    metas = tuple([
        meta for meta in metas
        if meta is not type and meta not in seen and not seen_add(meta)])
    if not metas:
        return type(name, bases, attrmap)
    elif len(metas) == 1:
        return metas[0](name, bases, attrmap)
    newmeta_name = "__".join(meta.__name__ for meta in metas)
    newmeta = type(newmeta_name, metas, {})
    return newmeta(name, bases, attrmap)

class M_A(type):
    pass

class M_B(type):
    pass

class A:
    __metaclass__ = M_A

class B:
    __metaclass__ = M_B

class C(A, B):
    __metaclass__ = meta_class_synthesize


print type(C)  # prints "<class '__main__.M_A__M_B'>"
```

Comment: Ok yes, this is great.  I think part of it is each time I get in to thinking about the nittygritty of the metaclass class, I lose site of the fact that what I'm doing is creating a callable that takes name, bases, and attrs.  By cutting out the fancy footwork, this focuses in on that fact well.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find that `__bases__` is not part of the class namespace. The class namespace is passed to the metaclass as the third parameter; the bases are passed as the *second* parameter. They are totally separate until the class is created.

So what you'll need to do is write a metaclass that synthesizes the metaclass you want, then uses that to create the class. I have no idea if that'll actually work, but I can't see any reason why it wouldn't.

Comment: Yeah, I know I have to create a new metaclass that has for its bases the metaclasses of both primary class bases, but I want to do that dynamically.  If I do it statically, and I ever change the metaclasses of the bases, or add another base class in the mix somewhere with another metaclass, it will break things up and down the stack.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, but I believe you can do that with a metaclass. Have the metaclass do what you're talking about in its `__new__()` method. Then use the generated metaclass to create the class and return it. It will probably need to recognize itself so it doesn't get into a recursive loop.

Comment: If that doesn't work, I'd use a class decorator for the job. Actually, that might be better since it's outside the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it.  So you are saying from the metaclass `MC` of class `C`, I will have access to `C.__bases__`, so I could dynamically generate a metaclass from `MC.__new__()` that would then be used as the metaclass for `C`.  Pardon the cultural reference, but, "I herd you like metaclasses, so I put a metaclass in your metaclass so you could metaclass while you metaclass."

Comment: Yes that's pretty much exactly it. It's Xzibit all the way down.

Comment: The class decorator approach has the pitfall that you can't use the bases on the class itself (because Python won't let you), so you have to pass the bases to the decorator, and have the class as written derive from `object`. You'd only use the class as written for its `__dict__`.